# MASM StdOut integer value instead of ASCII representation

Tags: assembly, stdout, masm

I'm writing on of my first assembly programs in MASM, and am trying to print out a number using `StdOut`. Here is my code (snippet):

```
.data
Su dword 0
.code
start:
        mov Su, 65
        invoke StdOut, addr Su
        invoke ExitProcess, 0
end start
```

The problem is, instead of printing out `65`, it prints out the ASCII representation `A`. How can I make it print out an integral value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StdOut` takes a string argument, so you'll need to convert the dword to a decimal string. This is not hard to do by hand, or you can look for a library function to do it. The discussion at http://www.masm32.com/board/index.php?topic=16316.0 would suggest one of `dwtoa`, `itoa`, or `crt_itoa`, depending on what libraries you're linking with. (Note that the link is talking about ascii->integer, so it uses atoi and atodw.)